# What is the best database solution to store large often updated datasets?

Tags: database, relational-database, updates, nosql

I have a `MySQL` table with `dataset > 50 M` rows and counting.

There are many updates and inserts that are taking more and more times (data set is increasing) so I am worried that it will be a bottleneck over time.

Can anyone suggest better solution that has faster updates and has also fast lookup?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not an expert I have also come across the same problem and was told to look in to load distribution...

In essence you will be running two or more servers and the software will direct the request to the servers based on load.

But a question to you are you using the database as efficiently as poss?  for example I am currently looking at changing my database from using the full text string in (backend) to replacing regularly used works with numbers for example:

```
1 = Tom
2 = Sabastian
3 = Paris
4 = Something Else
5 = Foo Bar Barry
```

Let me know you thoughts and practices

S

Comment: If inserts are taking more and  more time you can check I/O for waits and look to index fragmentation.  For updates, make sure your targeted (non "do everything") updates are using one or more indexes to identify the rows to be updated.  You can also look again to your indexes for fragmentation.  In many cases, the update will be based on a value in another table - make sure that the query to retrieve that value is based on an indexed query as well.